# Html.Encode importance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding, nerddinner, html.actionlink

I'm working through the NerdDinner MVC tutorial and came across this and was wondering about.

On page 62 of the pdf they have the following:

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Upcoming Dinners</h2>
    <ul>
        <% foreach (var dinner in Model) { %>
            <li>
                <a href="/Dinners/Details/<%=dinner.DinnerID %>">
                    <%= Html.Encode(dinner.Title) %>
                </a>
                on
                <%= Html.Encode(dinner.EventDate.ToShortDateString())%>
                @
                <%= Html.Encode(dinner.EventDate.ToShortTimeString())%>
            </li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
```

They then state that instead of using an `<a>` tag that you can use the Html helper like so:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(dinner.Title, "Details", new { id=dinner.DinnerID }) %>
```

The question is:  Isn't it still important to Html.Encode the dinner.Title from the Model when using this approach?  If not, why not?  If so, is there a way to use the Html.ActionLink and still use Html.Encode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` already calls `Encode`, internally (see the source). You don't want to do it twice.

Comment: Awesome, where can I look at the source for the Html helpers included with MVC?